# image keeps loading after image select in admin grid in magento2

Tags: magento2, admin

hello everyone I am uploading an image in admin grid after selecting the image the image keeps loading and nothing change 
screenshot
[image]

code to save image

```
public function modifyData(array $data)
{
    $items = $this->collection->getItems();
    /** @var $image \Turiknox\SampleImageUploader\Model\Image */
    foreach ($items as $image) {
        $_data = $image->getData();
        if (isset($_data['image']) && $_data['image'] != '') {
            $imageArr = [];
            $imageArr[0]['name'] = $image->getImage();
            $imageArr[0]['url'] = $image->getImageUrl();
            $_data['image'] = $imageArr;
        }
        $image->setData($_data);
        $data[$image->getId()] = $_data;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

[ref](https://github.com/Turiknox/magento2-sample-imageuploader/blob/e2d0a7ba1ff3bcd11c1a243225c7977e617e98eb/app/code/Turiknox/SampleImageUploader/Ui/DataProvider/Image/Form/Modifier/ImageData.php):

Comment: Follow this demo image upload module.
https://github.com/Turiknox/magento2-sample-imageuploader

Comment: in have followed this demo this demo has this error

Comment: check in in console. and 
`fileuploder.js` file is responsible to upload image check this file in magento_ui core module